# How to avoid flickering issue in browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, toggle, flicker

I am working on a website in which I am facing a flickering issue repeatedly in many browsers. Its very hard to reproduce so I am not using fiddle here.

I believe the code which is causing the problem is:

```
const yaxis = xyaxis.querySelector('.y-axis');   

yaxis.classList.toggle('y-axis-scroll-bar', .35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight);
```

**Problem Statement**:

On commenting the above two lines in my codebase, the flickering issue doesn't seems to appear anymore.

I am wondering why **removing the above two lines** in my codebase has solved the flickering issue in chrome and in other browsers.

Comment: Html has probably been rendered for a while before that code gets called and it has a layout effect changing that class. Too many unknowns without a [mcve].

Comment: @charlietfl It will take me a while to make a fiddle and in the actual website as well it very hard to reproduce but it comes sometimes.

Comment: @charlietfl Probably it has to do something with the view-port height `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight`

Comment: Lots of reasons it could be flickering. Do some reading up on the page life cycle. Can be a long enough delay getting all the script resources loaded before that line gets called, or there are images to load and you use a `window.onload` before calling it....just to name a few

Comment: @charlietfl I will do more research on the page life cycle. Do you know what exactly this line is doing `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight` ? I know it has to do something with the view port height.

Comment: It returns a boolean to turn it into `toggle(className, true/false)`

Comment: I did a bit reading on it. When this line is true `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight` then toggle comes in effect.

Comment: Right but it is not happening the instant the html is visible so there is enough time lag to see it cause a flicker in layout when it actually does occur

Comment: Those 2 lines are inside the javascript file. On page load, I can see that javascript file is loading.by checking sources tab (CTRL+P and looking for a file)

Comment: Also flicker issue happens only after certain time on page load not instantly. We have to zoom-in/zoom-out in order to see the flciker issue on chrome.

Comment: @charlietfl Are you around ?

Comment: Yes but there simply isn't enough known to help further. This needs to be debugged by seeing where that code gets executed and by using browser developer tools to analyze the dom

Comment: Alright, I will get back to you when I have enough information.